# Unblock widget without lose focus

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a focused widget and a blocked widget, when I unblock the blocked widget, the focus is stolen

Look this example (click once on the run button) : http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520field%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField()%253B%250A%250Avar%2520button%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522A%2520button%2522)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520blocker%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.core.Blocker(button)%253B%250A%250Athis.getRoot().add(field%252C%2520%257Btop%253A%252010%252C%2520left%253A%252010%257D)%253B%250Athis.getRoot().add(button%252C%2520%257Btop%253A100%252C%2520left%253A10%257D)%253B%250A%250Ablocker.block()%253B%250Afield.focus()%253B%250Ablocker.unblock()%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that what you try to achieve is what the `qx.ui.core.Blocker` was intended for. The implementation does not take in account that the focus is moved during the block.

If you call the method `block` the code tries to determine the widget which was focused *before* the block is done and saves that widget, then sets the focus to the widget to be blocked and restores the focus to the saved widget when unblocking.

With a small addition in a subclass, you could avoid that focus save/restore:

```
  qx.Class.define("qx.ui.core.MyBlocker",
  {
    extend : qx.ui.core.Blocker,

    properties : {

      backupActiveWidget :
      {
        check : "Boolean",
        init : true
      }

    },

    members : {  
      // overridden
      _backupActiveWidget : function() {
        if(this.getBackupActiveWidget() === false) {
          return
        }

        this.base(arguments);
      }
    }
  });
```

and use the blocker this way:

```
var blocker = new qx.ui.core.MyBlocker(widgetToBeBlocked);
blocker.setBackupActiveWidget(false);
```

This should prevent the blocker from *stealing* the focus which may be set during the block.